# Unable to push changes from local to remote branch in GitHub due to access rights

Tags: github, git-commit

I'm listed as the owner of the organization which has the mentioned repository. I cut a branch and I'm working on this branch locally. A few days back I was able to push my local changes to the remote branch but now I'm getting an error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm using IntelliJ as my editor. Also, I'm able to pull the changes from remote branch.
Before writing this post I've generated a new Personal access token and added it to IntelliJ.

Not sure how to go about it.

Edit:

I'm selected the following while generating my Personal Access Token
[image]

Edit 2:

The issue was due to the repository. Keeping the question since it's been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the newly generated token is generated with write access permissions, just try to generate a new token and check if there are any mentioned options about the permissions.

Comment: I've edit the post. I've added a SS of the things I've selected for my PAT

Comment: tried pushing again, getting this error now 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for <Repo Link>.

Did another push without changing anything, getting the same error: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Pretty weird!?

Comment: `Invalid username or password` for this you need to check your configured git user and credentials on your local machine.

Comment: If you are confident that your permission on Github is correct, you may try cloning the repo somewhere else on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite generic one - it can be due to a lack of permissions OR due to incorrect token that is saved in password safe or Credential helper.

Please make sure that you have "Use credential helper" is disabled under File | Settings | Version Control | Git

Then, please check that sufficient permissions are granted to JetBrains Integration in GitHub.

Also it might worth following:
https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-membership-in-organizations/requesting-organization-approval-for-oauth-apps

Also, make sure that URL under Git | Manage remotes does not contain username.